# curl request to Microsoft Sharepoint API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, curl, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

Is there a simple way to use a [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) request to the REST API to access a file on my Sharepoint account? For example

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <some-key-here>" https://mysharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists
```

I have read all the documentation about [authentication and authorization for apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142384.aspx), but in this case I don't have an "application" that I can register. I simply need an API key of some kind to use in REST requests. How can I use the REST API in this way?

I appreciate any insight into this problem.

Answer (score 10):

Create a bash script:

```
$ nano get_access_token.sh
```

Paste the next content to it, changing `YourTenant`, `client_id`, `client_secret` to your own values (you could get in Sharepoint's part below).

```bash
wwwauthenticate=$(curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer" -s "https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/" | grep -i "www-authenticate")
bearer_realm=$(echo $wwwauthenticate | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | tr -d '"')
app_id=$(echo $wwwauthenticate | awk -F"," '{print $2}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'  | tr -d '"')

grant_type="grant_type=client_credentials"
cl_id="client_id=c2xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx@$bearer_realm"
cl_secret="client_secret=3zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
res="resource=$app_id/YourTenant.sharepoint.com@$bearer_realm"
url="https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/$bearer_realm/tokens/OAuth/2"
content_type="Conent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

access_token=$(curl -X POST -H $content_type --data-urlencode $grant_type --data-urlencode $cl_id --data-urlencode $cl_secret --data-urlencode $res -s $url | awk -F":" '{print $NF}' | tr -d '"}')

echo $access_token
```

Apply proper permissions: `chmod 700 get_access_token.sh`

**You could use `curl` with that token the next way:**

`curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $(./get_access_token.sh)" -H "Accept: application/json;odata=verbose" -s "https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web"`

You could replace `./` by the full path to the script.

### Sharepoint's part:

1. Register a new app by

   - following `https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx` link
   - generating **Client Id** and ** Client Secret** values
   - filling **Title**, **App Domain** and **Redirect URI** fields (I've input localhost.com as on the picture - it works)
   - clicking **Create** button
     [image]
2. Save somewhere into file the next parameters:

   ```
   The app identifier has been successfully created.
   Client Id:      898c898f-89238-43d0-4b2d-7a64c26f386a
   Client Secret:  4/T+21I1DSoAJdOX9DL1Ne4KssEaP7rqb11gdtskhXn=
   Title:          SomeTitle
   App Domain:     localhost.com
   Redirect URI:   https://localhost.com/default.aspx
   ```
3. Apply permissions to this app by

   - following `https://YourTennant.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`
   - inserting **Client Id**: `898c898f-89238-43d0-4b2d-7a64c26f386a` into **App Id** field
   - clicking **Lookup** button
   - pasting into **Permission Request XML** the next code (in my case I needed only `Read` access, so I changed `Right`s value from `FullControl` to `Read`):

     ```xml
     <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
         <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
     </AppPermissionRequests>
     ```
   - **Create** bottom button clicking
     [image]
   - **Trust it** button clicking

[Here's Postman related but similar answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/281249/88705)

Answer (score 3):

If this is still relevant, this did it for me:

`curl https://mysharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists -v --ntlm --negotiate -u user:password`

You basically authenticate using ntlm (Note that some sharepoints might require Kerberos) and then can easily access the REST API like you can via browser.

---

Edit does not work with Office 365 apparently.

Comment: But this will not work for an Office 365 tenant, will it?

Comment: I think it should. Unfortunately I cant test it right now, can you maybe confirm that it doesn't work or works?

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work, at least for me: `Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.`