# How to upload files to SharepointOnline using curl on Linux

Tags: linux, curl, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to automate file uploads to SharePoint Online.  Problem is I keep getting 401 unauthorized error when trying to upload the files.  I created a script to retrieve the token as suggested in [curl request to Microsoft Sharepoint API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449299/curl-request-to-microsoft-sharepoint-api), but uploads are still failing, even though I do get a positive response when running `curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $(./get_access_token.sh)" -H "Accept: application/json;odata=verbose" -s "https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web"`. I have afeeling that I am just malforming my curl command.  Any suggestion on command format to be using?